# Warning: Could not start program with arguments. Warning: Exec format error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, opensuse

Hello I'm trying to make a Shell script in opensuse to create MySqlUsers but when I try to run it I get this error:

> Warning: Could not start program '/home/thomas/Scripts/MySqlCreateUser.sh' with arguments '/home/thomas/Scripts/MySqlCreateUser.sh'.
>
> Warning: Exec format error

Any Idea what I can do?

Comment: You need to post your script for people to be able to help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to start this from a KDE menu item.

You need to make sure that:

1. Your script has a proper shebang on the first line (like `#!/bin/bash`)
2. Your script is executable (`chmod +x /home/thomas/Scripts/MySqlCreateUser.sh`)

Comment: Huge thanks, I did the first step and it works, do I need this line in all my shell files?

Comment: Yep. That line tells the OS that this is a bash script and not some other kind of script or a binary. You can search StackOverflow for "shebang" to get some related information.

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to Grisha Levit's answer:
If the .sh file is simply a "java -jar ..." then just enter "java -jar ..." as the cmd in the KDE Menu Editor.